# .NET build multiple projects with vs code

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up my Visual Studio code to build multiple dotnet projects at run.

My task.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build_task",
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": [
                "build", "${workspaceRoot}/main/project.json", "-o", "${workspaceRoot}/obj/", "--framework", "netcoreapp1.1"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works. But when I add this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build_task",
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": [
                "build", 
                "-o", "${workspaceRoot}/obj/",
                "${workspaceRoot}/main/project.json", "-f", "netcoreapp1.1",
                "${workspaceRoot}/pluginSample/project.json", "-f", "netstandard1.6"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get this error:

```
Unexpected value 'netstandard1.6' for option 'framework'
```

But when I compile it manually it works:

```
dotnet build -f netstandard1.6
```